# HttpClient not filling out input box from a remote site

Tags: android, http-post, httpclient

I've created an app where the user enters a name and when the button send is pressed the form from a remote server will be filled from the user input. but somehow its not working, its not filling the input box, I'm not getting any error so I'm not sure whats wrong.

here's my code for the mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button send;
    EditText name;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFName);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);

        final String sname = name.getText().toString();

        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        HttpClient postClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        String postReq = "http://10.0.2.2/formcode.php";
                        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(postReq);
                        List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("element_8_1", sname));
                        UrlEncodedFormEntity postEntity = null;
                        try {
                            postEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams);
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        request.setEntity(postEntity);

                        HttpResponse response = null;
                        try {
                            response = postClient.execute(request);
                        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

                String url = "http://10.0.2.2/formcode.php";
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

thanks in advance.

**EDITED**

here is the site code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>App Test Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./data/form_6/css/view.css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/view.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendar.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="main_body" >

    <img id="top" src="images/top.png" alt="" />
    <div id="form_container">

        <h1><a>App Test Form</a></h1>
        <form id="form_6" class="digitalfuture"  method="post" action="#main_body">
                    <div class="form_description">
            <h2>App Test Form</h2>
            <p></p>
        </div>                      
            <ul >

                    <li id="li_8" >
        <label class="description">Name <span id="required_8" class="required">*</span></label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_8_1" name= "element_8_1" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="8" value="" />
            <label>First</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_8_2" name= "element_8_2" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="14" value="" />
            <label>Last</label>
        </span><p class="guidelines" id="guide_8"><small>Please tell us your name</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_9" >
        <label class="description">Phone Number <span id="required_9" class="required">*</span></label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_9_1" name="element_9_1" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text" /> -
            <label for="element_9_1">(###)</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_9_2" name="element_9_2" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text" /> -
            <label for="element_9_2">###</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_9_3" name="element_9_3" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" type="text" />
            <label for="element_9_3">####</label>
        </span>
        <p class="guidelines" id="guide_9"><small>Please tell us your phone number</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_10" >
        <label class="description">Alternate Phone Number </label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_10_1" name="element_10_1" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text" /> -
            <label for="element_10_1">(###)</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_10_2" name="element_10_2" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text" /> -
            <label for="element_10_2">###</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_10_3" name="element_10_3" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" type="text" />
            <label for="element_10_3">####</label>
        </span>
        <p class="guidelines" id="guide_10"><small>Please tell us an alternate phone number to contact you at</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_11" >
        <label class="description" for="element_11">Email <span id="required_11" class="required">*</span></label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_11" name="element_11" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="your@email.com" /> 
        </div> 
        </li>

    </div>
    <img id="bottom" src="images/bottom.png" alt="" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: because your request is different from the previous one. Ideally you should not do it this way, but if you insist the way to do it would be to take the response and show in the browser local to the app.

Comment: then how do suggest i should do it?

Comment: Don't use `Thread` class in the `onCreate`. Do the connection as a background task by using `AsyncTask` as in [this example](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/handling-http-post-method-in-android/)

Comment: I dont get it. You open a browser window but you also post at the same time? Huh?

Comment: first I post the text to the form in the server, I'm just checking if its working thats why I'm opening a browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may be because the value you're sending in the parameters is blank. `sname` is set outside of the `onClickListener` so the value doesn't update when the button is clicked.  It just gets the value that's already in the text box.  I would recommend moving the code to an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (There's lots of good tutorials out there on this) as AnujAroshA suggested.  You want to have something like this:

```
private class SubmitForm extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                String sName = params[0];

                // Rest of the code you had here
            }
}
```

What this will do is create a task that runs in the background and not on the UI thread.  Then to run it, just modify the `onClickListener` to say

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new SubmitForm().execute(name.getText().toString());
}
```

So then this will actually start the riequest.  It's similar to the way you had it with `Thread`s but a bit more android offical.

Comment: ok sir thank you, I was reading an article about asynctask this is my firs time with this one so It might take some time, you would be a very big help.

Comment: I'm getting an error in this line of code
`new SubmitForm(name.getText()).execute();` I changed the code to this
`new SubmitForm(name.getText().toString()).execute();` but I'm still getting this error `The constructor MainActivity.SubmitForm(String) is undefined`

Comment: Oops, my mistake!  Move the `name.getText().toString()` portion into the `execute` call.  I updated the example

Comment: now its saying `The method execute(String...) in the type AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> is not applicable for the arguments (Editable)` should i change it to runnable?

Comment: Do you have the `toString()` call at the end?  I think you need that

Comment: my bad, its fine now... thank, I'll go and see if its working

Comment: Its still not working sir, wait I'll edit my question, I'll add the webpage code may the pagecode has a problem...

Comment: Oh I see now.  Does that webpage use Javascript to process the form?  I don't think that's going to work the way you want it to on Android.  `POST` requests are generally meant to be sent to some sort of script (PHP, ASP.net, etc) where they are processed.  What yours does is just send a webpage some data and it doesn't do anything with it (as far as I know).  So it's not going to fill out the text box like you want it to.  If that webpage has some sort of script that the data is submitted to, POST your data to that instead.